# Python 3: how to save memory when running code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

a, b are 2 super long lists, they have same amount of int elements(n).

```
a = [3, 5, 2, 5, 6, ...]
b = [2, 5, 6, 23, 25, ...]
```

now we have 2 random int x and y. now what we need to do is to calculate how many pairs of a, b meet the below requirement:  For each a,b pair, if a>x and b>y then counter + 1.

then I wrote below code:

```
a = [3, 5, 2, 5, 6, ...]
b = [2, 5, 6, 23, 25, ...]

counter = 0
for i in range(n):
    if a[i]>x and b[i]>y:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

I got the correct answer when the list is short, but got "Out of memory" when the list was long enough. My question is what is the correct way to deal with memory issue?

Comment: The only things that are large in this example are `a` and `b` themselves. The for loop won't consume much memory because any temporary objects it creates are freed on the next loop. If you could load them more compactly, say into a numpy array, you may have better luck.

Comment: How do you load `a` and `b`? That's the key to this question which is being left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are these two lists generated?

One way to save memory in this case is use `generator`, so that the entire list is not loaded into memory.

A simple example is `range(10)`, you can do `range(10000000000)` without worrying about memory, because the numbers in the whole range is not fully created in the memory, but generated when needed.

If the two lists are read from files save on your disk, you can read them in chunks: use `read(chunksize)` instead of `read()`.